# Kafka Mirrormaker2 config optimization

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, strimzi, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I am setting up Strimzi kafka Mirrormaker2 in our test environment which receives on an average 100k messages/5 mins. we have around 25 topics and 900 partitions in total for these topics. The default configuration i set up is mirroring only 60k messages/5 mins to the DR cluster. I am trying to optimize this configuration for better throughput and latency.

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
 kind: KafkaMirrorMaker2
 spec:
  clusters:
  - alias: source
   authentication:
    certificateAndKey:
     certificate: user.crt
     key: user.key
     secretName: mirrormaker1
    type: tls
   bootstrapServers: bootstrap1:443
   tls:
    trustedCertificates:
    - certificate: ca.crt
     secretName: cert-source
  - alias: target
   authentication:
    certificateAndKey:
     certificate: user.crt
     key: user.key
     secretName: mirrormaker-dr
    type: tls
   bootstrapServers: bootstrap2:443
   config:
     offset.flush.timeout.ms: 120000
   tls:
    trustedCertificates:
    - certificate: ca.crt
     secretName: dest-cert
  connectCluster: target
  livenessProbe:
   initialDelaySeconds: 40
   periodSeconds: 40
   timeoutSeconds: 30
  metricsConfig:
   type: jmxPrometheusExporter
   valueFrom:
    configMapKeyRef:
     key: mm2-metrics-config.yaml
     name: mm2-metrics
  mirrors:
  - checkpointConnector:
    config:
     checkpoints.topic.replication.factor: 3
    tasksMax: 10
   groupsPattern: .*
   heartbeatConnector:
    config:
     heartbeats.topic.replication.factor: 3
   sourceCluster: source
   sourceConnector:
    config:
     consumer.request.timeout.ms: 150000
     offset-syncs.topic.replication.factor: 3
     refresh.topics.interval.seconds: 60
     replication.factor: 3
     source.cluster.producer.enable.idempotence: "true"
     sync.topic.acls.enabled: "true"
     target.cluster.producer.enable.idempotence: "true"
    tasksMax: 60
   targetCluster: target
   topicsPattern: .*
  readinessProbe:
   initialDelaySeconds: 40
   periodSeconds: 40
   timeoutSeconds: 30
  replicas: 4
  resources:
   limits:
    cpu: 9
    memory: 30Gi
   requests:
    cpu: 5
    memory: 15Gi
  version: 2.8.0
```

With the above config i don't see any errors in the log files.

I tried to fine tune the config for more throughput and latency as follows

```
      consumer.max.partition.fetch.bytes: 2097152
      consumer.max.poll.records: 1000
      consumer.receive.buffer.bytes: 131072
      consumer.request.timeout.ms: 200000
      consumer.send.buffer.bytes: 262144
      offset-syncs.topic.replication.factor: 3
      producer.acks: 0
      producer.batch.size: 20000
      producer.buffer.memory: 30331648
      producer.linger.ms: 10
      producer.max.request.size: 2097152
      producer.message.max.bytes: 2097176
      producer.request.timeout.ms: 150000
```

I am seeing the following errors in the logs now but the data is still flowing and see the number of messages increased slightly to around ~65k/5mins. I also increased the tasksmax count from 60 to 800 and replicas from 4 to 8 but i don't see any difference doing this.Also the N/w Bytes in is around ~20 MiB/s. Even though i further increased consumer.request.timeout.ms the below error didn't disappear..

2022-04-26 04:09:51,223 INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-null-1601, groupId=null] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=629190882, epoch=65) to node 4: (org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler) [task-thread-us-ashburn-1->us-phoenix-1-dr.MirrorSourceConnector-759]
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException

Is there anything i can do to increase the throughput and decrease the latency?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't configured Strimzi kafka Mirrormaker before, but at first look, the producer and consumer configs seem to be the same as what is exposed by the `kafka-clients` library. Assuming that is the case, the producer's `batch.size`, which is set to 20000, is not number of records. It is in bytes, which means, with this config, the producer will transmit a maximum of only 20 kilobytes per send. Try increasing it to 65,536(64 kilobytes) or higher. If the throughput still doesn't increase, increase `linger.ms` to `100` or higher, so that the producer waits longer for each batch to fill up before triggering a send

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i did try the following config as well...but the throughput went down.

Comment: consumer.fetch.max.wait.ms: 1000
          consumer.fetch.min.bytes: 100000
          consumer.max.poll.records: 10000
          consumer.request.timeout.ms: 200000
          producer.acks: 0
          producer.batch.size: 100000
          producer.buffer.memory: 524288000
          producer.linger.ms: 50